# Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, cors

I have a Laravel application and all the Api's are running fine apart from the upload excel Api hosted on an AWS server.

Below is the error I am getting for the excel upload or any kind of upload.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost/products. (Reason: CORS
>   preflight channel did not succeed).

The below headers are added to the **bootstrap/app.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true');
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the configuration because why would only one api would fail apart from other api's.

Also attaching ajax script

```
$.ajax({
 type: frm.attr('method'),
 url: 'SERVER_URL',
 data: formData,
 crossDomain: true,
 dataType: "multipart/form-data",
 processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
 contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
 headers: {
      'Accept':'multipart/form-data',
      'contentType':'Application/json'
  },
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer AUTH_KEY")
 },
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Below is the image of the network

[image]

[image]

Comment: "CORS preflight channel did not succeed" — So use the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to find out what the response to the OPTIONS request actually is, and then fix it.

Comment: `crossDomain: true` is pointless unless you are making a *same* origin request that gets redirected to become cross origin.

Comment: `dataType: "multipart/form-data",` and `'Accept':'multipart/form-data',` are nonsense. You are not expecting the server to respond with `multipart/form-data`

Comment: `'contentType':'Application/json'` is nonsense. You aren't sending JSON. You're sending a form data object's serialisation.

Comment: Is the AWS Server the same as your localhost?

Comment: @RiggsFolly — It can't be, by definition.

Comment: Re edit: "Below is the image of the network" — That shows the response to a POST request, not the preflight OPTIONS request that the error message was complaining about.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The AWS server is different to my front-end server.

Comment: @Quentin added both the request OPTIONS and POST

Comment: Why does the screenshot say `*` when the code says `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost');`?

Comment: It also looks like you are using some HTTP testing tool to make these requests instead of the Network tab of the browser's Developer Tools, which would suggest you aren't seeing the same request that the browser is actually making.

Comment: If the **remote** resource is `http://localhost` then the **origin** resource clearly is not `http://localhost` something is a bit off here.

Comment: i have updated the header origin and still the same

Comment: Try this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75257012/1767847

Answer (score -5):

I think that allowing **your localhost** is no more secure then just try to set the **header()** to

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: It's *a lot* more secure.